# Checking 2 Million Files for Duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, filesystems, duplicates, checksum

We need to check 2 million files to see if they have any duplicates.

What would the best way be of doing that?

http://www.easyduplicatefinder.com/
We have used this tool to do roughly 20k files

But soon we will have to do 2 million

Any ideas on how this could be done in an efficient manner?

Sas

Comment: Any duplicate files? Or any duplicate file contents? Such as if you had a CSV that looked like: a,a,b,b,c,d,e,f (that would have 4 duplicate values) The answer varies based on what you mean

Comment: Why doesn't the software you linked suit your needs?  This is not a complicated problem and I would imagine any software designed for it would suit your needs - unless they limit how many files you compare, or something.

Answer (score 5):

Create checksums in [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Applications) or [SHA-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) (preferable, as the collisions are less likely), or even both (when collisions are so very unlikely, that you can sleep well knowing you have made no mistake).

Then compare checksums. This will compare the contents. If you want to also compare the names of the files, take them into account when comparing.

That is all. Quite (very) reliable.

Comment: you can completely eliminate false positives by comparing file contents as binary strings wherever hash collisions occurred.

Comment: @rambocoder: You do not know if it is a false positive unless you do the comparison of the contents, anyway ;) The idea is just to shorten the process. Instead of comparing the content every time hashes match, you can prepare hashes using another algorithm (if not already created), save them (for future use) and compare. This way you will optimize it somehow (by generating additional hashes only in case of necessity). But comparing whole contents when there are many large duplicates is pretty troublesome.